# trying to search inside chmod with command

Tags: linux, chmod

I am trying to find commands with the word "symbolic" inside the contents

If I type

```
   man chmod
```

and

```
   /symbolic
```

you can see that chmod command has the line of "new modes of the file will also be printed, in both octal and symbolic notation. ~ "

So I was expecting if I type

```
   man -f "symbolic"
```

the chmod command shows up, but it doesn't

Why not? And how do I look up the words in "Full", not "short", command man page? so that I can look up chmod by searching the word "symbolic"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `-K` option for `man`:

> -K, --global-apropos
>               Search for text in all manual pages.  This is a brute-force search, and is likely to take  some  time;  if
>               you  can,  you  should  specify  a section to reduce the number of pages that need to be searched.  Search
>               terms may be simple strings (the default), or regular expressions if the --regex option is used.

This will, by default, queue all of the `man` pages that match your search pattern up for opening in your $PAGER. To just view the list of `man` pages that contain your search term, pass the `-w` option as well:

> -w, --where, --location
>               Don't actually display the manual pages, but do print the location(s) of the source nroff files that would
>               be formatted.

Depending on your search term, this could return *a lot* of results...